# SSL connection failing with no Certificate Request from the server, connecting to Nginx on AWS from a local Websphere AS running on Java 6

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, nginx, sni

I'm having a hard time connecting to a service with client authentication. The service ("SecureService") is on AWS. The clients are on a Linux VM on my Mac. Nginx on SecureService enforces Client Authentication on the resource I'm accessing on port 443. I can get a successful response connecting from the same VM to the same SecureService, using a proof of concept Java standalone application (openjdk 1.8.0_60) or other clients (wget, openssl), but not from the same Java code hosted on Websphere AS (admittedly relying on older libraries and IBM J9 VM, build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0). When remapping the SecureService hostname to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts, though, that same java code on Websphere AS connects successfully to a local openSSL server requiring client authentication from the same Certification Authority. The response from SecureServer in the failing connection reports "400 No required SSL certificate was sent"... "400 Bad Request", but tcpdump packet captures show it's NOT sending a Certificate Request, whereas it is in all the other cases. This is puzzling and leads me to think there is something in the ClientHello message that the server doesn't like, though ClientHello messages in successful and failing connections are very similar.

A quite odd detail is also that tcpdump never captures the first TCP SYN packet from my client to the server in the failing communication, while it captures the rest (SYN + ACK from the server, then ACK from the client) and all the packets (SYN, SYN + ACK, ACK) on all other communications.

All communications use TLSv1.2 in all their parts.

Failing connection:

```
    (client <--> server)
    <-- SYN, ACK
    --> ACK
    --> Client Hello
    <-- ACK
    <-- Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
    --> ACK
    --> Client Key Exchange
    <-- ACK
    --> Change Cypher Spec
    <-- ACK
    --> Encrypted Handshake Message
    <-- ACK
    <-- Change Cypher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
    --> Application Data
    ...
```

Successful connection from proof of concept Java app:
(client <--> server)

```
    --> SYN
    <-- SYN, ACK
    --> ACK
    --> Client Hello
    <-- ACK
    <-- Server Hello
    <-- Certificate
    <-- Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
    --> ACK
    --> ACK
    --> [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    --> Certificate, Client Key Exchange
    <-- ACK
    --> Certificate Verify
    --> Change Cypher Spec
    --> Hello Request, Hello Request
    <-- ACK
    <-- Change Cypher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
    --> Application Data
    ...
```

Successful connection from Websphere AS to local openSSL:
(client <--> server)

```
    --> SYN
    <-- SYN, ACK
    --> ACK
    --> Client Hello
    <-- ACK
    <-- Server Hello, Certificate, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
    --> ACK
    --> Certificate, Client Key Exchange
    <-- ACK
    --> Certificate Verify
    --> Change Cypher Spec
    --> Encrypted Handshake Message
    <-- ACK
    <-- Change Cypher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
    --> Application Data
    ...
```

Failing Client Hello:

```
Frame 3: 332 bytes on wire (2656 bits), 332 bytes captured (2656 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture (25)
    Arrival Time: Feb 25, 2016 13:29:15.353437000 GMT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1456406955.353437000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.004839000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.004839000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.004868000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 3
    Frame Length: 332 bytes (2656 bits)
    Capture Length: 332 bytes (2656 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: sll:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssl]
    [Coloring Rule Name: TCP]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp]
Linux cooked capture
    Packet type: Sent by us (4)
    Link-layer address type: 1
    Link-layer address length: 6
    Source: CadmusCo_67:0a:c1 (08:00:27:67:0a:c1)
    Protocol: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS), Dst: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 316
    Identification: 0xf29d (62109)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0xc7f8 [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    Destination: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51512 (51512), Dst Port: 443 (443), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 276
    Source Port: 51512
    Destination Port: 443
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 276]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 277    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: *******AP***]
    Window size value: 14600
    [Calculated window size: 14600]
    [Window size scaling factor: -2 (no window scaling used)]
    Checksum: 0x8054 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [Bytes in flight: 276]
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 271
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 267
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random
                GMT Unix Time: Feb 25, 2016 13:29:15.000000000 GMT
                Random Bytes: 2ca99e72b66289fcd3f11bf2dc3ef464709b197e6dd6cdd5...
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: 28eef056a41440e760eaa9e3358a9cd56d8823fa130e9100...
            Cipher Suites Length: 128
            Cipher Suites (64 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xfeff)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0066)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0066)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0015)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
                Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xfeff)
                Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0xfefe)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 (0x0001)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA (0x0002)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 (0x003b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 66
            Extension: elliptic_curves
                Type: elliptic_curves (0x000a)
                Length: 24
                Elliptic Curves Length: 22
                Elliptic curves (11 curves)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192r1 (0x0013)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224r1 (0x0015)
                    Elliptic curve: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Elliptic curve: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160k1 (0x000f)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r1 (0x0010)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r2 (0x0011)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192k1 (0x0012)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224k1 (0x0014)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256k1 (0x0016)
            Extension: ec_point_formats
                Type: ec_point_formats (0x000b)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
            Extension: signature_algorithms
                Type: signature_algorithms (0x000d)
                Length: 28
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 26
                Signature Hash Algorithms (13 algorithms)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0603
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0601
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0503
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0501
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0403
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0401
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0303
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0301
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0203
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0201
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0402
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0202
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0101
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: MD5 (1)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
```

Successful Client Hello from proof of concept to SecureServer:

```
Frame 62: 306 bytes on wire (2448 bits), 306 bytes captured (2448 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (en0)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Feb 24, 2016 17:20:21.803009000 GMT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1456334421.803009000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.119948000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.119948000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 17.897514000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 62
    Frame Length: 306 bytes (2448 bits)
    Capture Length: 306 bytes (2448 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssl]
    [Coloring Rule Name: TCP]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp]
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_bc:c7:11 (a4:5e:60:bc:c7:11), Dst: CiscoInc_76:28:80 (a4:4c:11:76:28:80)
    Destination: CiscoInc_76:28:80 (a4:4c:11:76:28:80)
        Address: CiscoInc_76:28:80 (a4:4c:11:76:28:80)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: Apple_bc:c7:11 (a4:5e:60:bc:c7:11)
        Address: Apple_bc:c7:11 (a4:5e:60:bc:c7:11)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS), Dst: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 292
    Identification: 0xa8b7 (43191)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x279c [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    Destination: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 62197 (62197), Dst Port: 443 (443), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 240
    Source Port: 62197
    Destination Port: 443
    [Stream index: 9]
    [TCP Segment Len: 240]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 241    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: *******AP***]
    Window size value: 4122
    [Calculated window size: 131904]
    [Window size scaling factor: 32]
    Checksum: 0xc3c5 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
        No-Operation (NOP)
            Type: 1
                0... .... = Copy on fragmentation: No
                .00. .... = Class: Control (0)
                ...0 0001 = Number: No-Operation (NOP) (1)
        No-Operation (NOP)
            Type: 1
                0... .... = Copy on fragmentation: No
                .00. .... = Class: Control (0)
                ...0 0001 = Number: No-Operation (NOP) (1)
        Timestamps: TSval 928661973, TSecr 546145009
            Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 928661973
            Timestamp echo reply: 546145009
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [iRTT: 0.016102000 seconds]
        [Bytes in flight: 240]
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 235
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 231
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random
                GMT Unix Time: Feb 24, 2016 17:20:21.000000000 GMT
                Random Bytes: fbb67137e8cde6609cb570685f6c9b5a62eefbc12973b545...
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 58
            Cipher Suites (29 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 132
            Extension: elliptic_curves
                Type: elliptic_curves (0x000a)
                Length: 52
                Elliptic Curves Length: 50
                Elliptic curves (25 curves)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163k1 (0x0001)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163r2 (0x0003)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192r1 (0x0013)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224r1 (0x0015)
                    Elliptic curve: sect233k1 (0x0006)
                    Elliptic curve: sect233r1 (0x0007)
                    Elliptic curve: sect283k1 (0x0009)
                    Elliptic curve: sect283r1 (0x000a)
                    Elliptic curve: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Elliptic curve: sect409k1 (0x000b)
                    Elliptic curve: sect409r1 (0x000c)
                    Elliptic curve: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                    Elliptic curve: sect571k1 (0x000d)
                    Elliptic curve: sect571r1 (0x000e)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160k1 (0x000f)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r1 (0x0010)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r2 (0x0011)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163r1 (0x0002)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192k1 (0x0012)
                    Elliptic curve: sect193r1 (0x0004)
                    Elliptic curve: sect193r2 (0x0005)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224k1 (0x0014)
                    Elliptic curve: sect239k1 (0x0008)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256k1 (0x0016)
            Extension: ec_point_formats
                Type: ec_point_formats (0x000b)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
            Extension: signature_algorithms
                Type: signature_algorithms (0x000d)
                Length: 26
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 24
                Signature Hash Algorithms (12 algorithms)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0603
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0601
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0503
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0501
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0403
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0401
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0303
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0301
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0203
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0201
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0202
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0101
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: MD5 (1)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
            Extension: server_name
                Type: server_name (0x0000)
                Length: 36
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 34
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 31
                    Server Name: (OMITTED FOR SECURITY REASONS - IT CORRESPONDS TO THE DESTINATION HOSTNAME)
```

Tcpdump command line:

```
    sudo tcpdump -s 0 -n "port 443" -w /Repo/security/capture.cap -i any
```

Has anyone got any idea what could be going wrong? I don't have administration rights or even an account to log in on the server, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - I have found that the Nginx server requires a "server_name" extension to be specified in the Client Hello. In fact the following openssl command prompts the server to issue a Certificate Request...

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e/bin/openssl s_client -cert client_identity.crt -key client_identity.key -connect SecureServerHostName:443 -debug <post_request.txt -tls1_2 -servername SecureServerHostName
```

...while omitting the "-servername" option doesn't.

How I will force WebsphereAS to add that extension is another pair of shoes. Perhaps upgrading the version of Java will help, by updating the implementation of the TLS protocol.

---

Update: Yes, upgrading the IBM JDK from 1.6 to 1.7.1 worked, generating Client Hello messages with Server Name Indication, as mentioned [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_sslsecurecom.html) (*By default Java SE 7 enables Server Name Indication (SNI).*).